Convert a ytdl-core stream into a blob in Nodejs express
I'm working on a YouTube playlist audio downloader and have run into a snag (see below). I have no problem downloading the audio for one video; I simply pipe the stream to the response:
ytdl(info.videoDetails.videoId, {
  quality: "highestaudio",
  filter: "audioonly",
}).pipe(res);

What I would like to do is send the audio for every video in a playlist. I was thinking of sending the response as a "multipart/form-data" where each form segment contains the audio as a blob, as described in this article.
I'm having trouble converting the response from ytdl-core into a blob.  I think that I'm converting the stream itself, as opposed to the audio data.
The error that I'm getting is:
C:\Users\blackjacques\youtube-audio-downloader-master\node_modules\delayed-stream\lib\delayed_stream.js:33
source.on('error', function() {});
     ^
TypeError: source.on is not a function
    at DelayedStream.create (C:\Users\blackjacques\youtube-audio-downloader-master\node_modules\delayed-stream\lib\delayed_stream.js:33:10)
    at CombinedStream.append (C:\Users\blackjacques\youtube-audio-downloader-master\node_modules\combined-stream\lib\combined_stream.js:45:37)
    at FormData.append (C:\Users\blackjacques\youtube-audio-downloader-master\node_modules\form-data\lib\form_data.js:75:3)
    at C:\Users\blackjacques\youtube-audio-downloader-master\server.js:169:12
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:105:5)

Node.js v22.11.0

I am using "@distube/ytdl-core": "^4.15.1", "cors": "^2.8.5", "express": "^4.17.1", "form-data": "^4.0.1", and "ytpl": "^2.3.0".
Here is the relevant nodejs express server code:
getListOfSongsFromPlaylist = async (playlistUrl) => {
  console.log(playlistUrl)
  let playlist = await ytpl(playlistUrl);

  playlist.items = playlist.items.filter(song => song.isPlayable === true).map(song => {
      const title = (song.title.includes(song.author.name)) ? song.title : song.author.name + ' - ' + song.title;

      return {
          id: song.id,
          title: title,
          duration: song.duration
      }
    }
  );

  return playlist;
}

getAudioAsBlob = async (videoId) => {
  return await new Response(
    ytdl(videoId, {
      quality: "highestaudio",
      filter: "audioonly",
    }).blob();
};

app.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  console.log(`Request: ${req.url}`);
  const form = new FormData();

  getListOfSongsFromPlaylist(req.body.url).then(async playlist => {
    console.log('Playlist name: ' + playlist.title);
    console.log('Total songs in playlist: ' + playlist.estimatedItemCount);

    playlist.items.forEach(async song => {
      const audioAsBlob = await getAudioAsBlob(song.id);
      form.append(song.title, audioAsBlob, {
        filename: `${song.title}.mp3`,
        contentType: 'audio/mpeg',
        knownLength: audioAsBlob.size,
      });
    });
  });

  // Set headers for multipart response.
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${form.getBoundary()}`, // boundary must match the one generated by form-data
    'Content-Length': form.getLengthSync(),
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 
  });

  // Write the multipart form data response.
  res.write(form.getBuffer());
  res.end();
});

Any ideas on how to convert the ytdl-core data into a blob?

I finally figured out how to convert the audio stream into a blob. The trick was to push the data onto an array in the 'data' event. I wound up converting the data array into a Buffer because the FormData didn't like the blob (which is a known issue). That's done in the 'end' event:
const getAudioAsBuffer = async (videoId) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const chunks = [];
    ytdl(videoId, {
      quality: "highestaudio",
      filter: "audioonly",
    }).on('data', (data) => {
      chunks.push(data);
    }).on('error', (err) => {
      console.log("error: " + err.message);
      reject(err.message);
    }).on('end', async () => {
      const arrayBuffer = await new Blob(chunks).arrayBuffer();
      resolve(Buffer.from(arrayBuffer));
    });
  });
};

Then it was just a matter of appending the Buffer to the form:
const form = new FormData();
const buffer = await getAudioAsBuffer(song.id);
  form.append(song.title, buffer, {
    filename: `${song.title}.mp3`,
    contentType: 'audio/mpeg',
    knownLength: buffer.length,
  });
  // Set headers for multipart response.
  res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${form.getBoundary()}`, // boundary must match the one generated by form-data
      'Content-Length': form.getLengthSync(),
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  });

  // Write the multipart form data response.
  res.write(form.getBuffer());
  res.end();

